# Combining find grep and tail

Tags: grep, find, tail

I am trying to find all files that start with a certain name, then go through each file to find lines that contains a string, then only print out the last line of each file that contain the string. Step by step, I first find all files in my directory that start with "A123"

```
find . -name 'A123*'
```

then get each line in the file that contains "Trial"

```
find . -name 'A123*' -exec grep 'Trial' {} \;
```

and then from here I only want to print the last line,

```
find . -name 'A123*' -exec grep 'Trial' {} | tail -1 \;
```

however, this last command does not work. How do I fix this to get what I am trying to get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`|` is a shell operator, so the whole output of `find` will be passed to `tail`. You need to run only a *single* command in exec by grouping all the commands to run and pass to `sh` or `bash` (or any shells you prefer)

```bash
find . -name 'A123*' -exec bash -c 'grep Trial "$1" | tail -1' grep {} \;
```

Or you can just use some other single commands for getting the last match from [How to grep the last occurrence of a line pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24014194/995714)

---

If you can make sure that you files contain **no special characters** like `` #$/\`&*~-... `` in their names you can use this

```bash
find . -name 'A123*' -exec bash -c "grep 'Trial' {} | tail -1" \;
```

But please be aware that strange things may happen there when there are unexpected names you didn't know. For more information read [Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/44425)